# Из mysql в excel сохраняет кракозябры

Tags: php, mysql, кодировка

Какие нужно добавить паметры, чтобы кириллицу в файле excel сохраняло?

```
 <?php
     include("config.php");
     global $connection;

     $ts = date('mdY-His');

     $sql = "SELECT * FROM price";
     $result = mysqli_query($connection, $sql) or die(mysqli_error());

     header("Content-Type: application/xls"); 
     header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=importdetails-".$ts.".xls");  
     header("Pragma: no-cache"); 
     header("Expires: 0");
     header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary ");

     // here is the formatting for Excel

     $sep = "\t"; //tabbed character

     // printing the column names

    /* for ($i = 0; $i < mysqli_num_fields($result); $i++) {
       echo mysqli_fetch_field($result,$i) . "\t";
     }*/

     print("\n");

     ?>

    <?php

     while($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result))
     {
       $schema_insert = "";
       for($j = 0; $j < mysqli_num_fields($result); $j++)
       {
         if(!isset($row[$j]))
           $schema_insert .= "NULL".$sep;
         elseif ($row[$j] != "")
           $schema_insert .= "$row[$j]".$sep;
         else
           $schema_insert .= "".$sep;
       }
       $schema_insert = str_replace($sep."$", "", $schema_insert);
       $schema_insert = preg_replace("/\r\n|\n\r|\n|\r/", " ", $schema_insert);
       $schema_insert .= "\t";
       print(trim($schema_insert));
       print "\n";
     }
     ?>
```

Comment: Мне кажется, или вы действительно выводите данные как plain-text, но зачем-то обзываете это `application/xls` ?

Но вообще для текстовых файлов с разделителями Excel адекватно ест обычную виндовую кодировку cp1251.

Comment: и куда ее записать эту кодировку?

Answer (score 1):

```
$mysqli->set_charset("utf8");
```

Указать еще в header кодировку выводимых данных  `charset=utf-8`.

xls имеет другой формат, не?

CSV обычно генерят для excel.